# File format in HIVE while creating tables

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am creating Hive external tables. The file format is text file. But the queries are taking long time to execute.

Is there any file format which I can use in order to access data quickly?

Answer (score 0):

ORC is by far the best file format for faster access of data from HIVE. Please note that you will have to make sure you load the data in sorted order for the column you search on to make the retrieval faster. This will make the load process slow.

I will suggest to use Partitioning along with ORC (ZLIB compressed) as this is something I have tested recently and seen good performance improvement.

for details on ORC file format you can refer (there are many good articles as well) 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC

Answer (score 0):

store it as ORC format and use tez execution engine 
`set hive.execution.engine=tez;`